# Send Mail using System.Net.Mail on a C# Windows Form

Tags: c#-2.0

Real simple question (so I thought), I just want to send mail from my form without having to Exit() or Restart().

I've looked through many examples and they all work but not within a form and the only way I've gotten it to work is by calling:

```
MySmtpClient.Send(MyMailMessage);  
MySmtpClient.Dispose();
```

But this is not available in .NET 2.0 (what my users' have on their machines).
So I tried using

MySmtpClient.SendAsync(MyMailMessage, MyMailMessage);

and then disposing after the SendCompleted event handler was triggered but it only gets triggered when I exit my form with `Application.Exit();`

Am I missing something simple?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/16/432854.aspx) 
[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=VS.80).aspx)

It looks like in .NET 2.0 SmtpClient did not implement IDisposable.  If it's eating your form's resources, how about:

```
SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
MailMessage myMailMessage = new MailMessage();
//set up email message
mySmtpClient.Send(myMailMessage);
SmptClient = null;
```

Comment: @ajdams: Maybe I'm misunderstanding... what, exactly, isn't working?  Is the mail not going at all?  Is it only going after the form closes?

Comment: Correct, the mail is only delivered after I close down the form.

Comment: @ajdams: can you post more of your code?  I've sent lots of email from forms, and I've never experienced this behavior.  Also, are you sure that email isn't sent until the form is closed?  Sometimes AD / Exchange can be somewhat finicky about delivering email generated through code...

Comment: I think you are right because I can get the same code you posted above to work on a different machine. Just this machine I originally developed the application on seems to not want to send out the email right away.